# Variable is taking value as a file instead of text (String)

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a bash script in which I manipulate a download link with user input dates and such to then download the file. 
When I run it, it throws an error
 `Final.sh: Line 16: http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT&a=02&b=13&c=1986&d=02&e=13&f=1986&g=@@d&ignore=.csv: No such file or directory`

The second problem is that at the bottom of the code I want the `wget "vString"` to get the updated (manipulated string) value of the variable but it's taking the original one for some reason. Any advice will help a lot!

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
vString="http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT&a=02&b=13&c=1986&d=02&e=13&f=1986&g=@@d&ignore=.csv"
read -p "Escriba el nombre de la empresa: " vEmpresa
read -p "Desea usar un rango de fechas? Y/N? " vRangoBoolean
read -p "Que  tipo de reporte es? " vTipo
if [ $vRangoBoolean == "Y" ]
then
read -p "Escribe el rango de fechas bajo el formato dd/mm/aa - dd/mm/aa:" vRango
elif [ $vRangoBoolean == "N" ]
then
read -p "Escriba el dia: " vDia
read -p "Escriba el mes: " vMes
read -p "Escriba el año: " vAno

${vString/@@d/$vTipo}
${vString/MSFT/$vEmpresa}
${vString/a=02/$vDia}

${vString/02/$vDia}
${vString/13/$vMes}
${vString/1986/$vAno}
${vString/08/$vDia}
${vString/13/$vMes}
${vString/1986/$vAno}
echo "La fecha del documento es: " "$vDia" de "$vMes" del "$vAno"
echo
wget "$vString"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Shell parameter substitutions like `${string/pattern/replacement}` don't modify the original value of `string`. You need to assign the result of each substitution back to the variable, e.g.

```
vString="${vString/@@d/$vTipo}"
vString="${vString/13/$vMes}"
vString="${vString/1986/$vAno}"
```

and so on.